# int being inserted into middle of a string, sqlite selection, why no error in this code?

Tags: java, android, database, string, sqlite

how is it possible that the following code below works correctly, despite the variable rowNum is an int and not a String?   how is this possible or what is going on here?

is the int rowNum variable being converted into a string automatically when the string is assigned to the String selection variable?

```
  public String getTableString(int rowNum){
  String tableString = "";
  String[] columns = new String[]{TABLE_STRING};
  String selection = _ID + " = '" + rowNum + "';";
  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query
  (MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, selection, null, null, null, null);
```

why do i not have to use Integer.toString() in this case and it still works?

this does not make any sense, by normal rules it should be required to use Integer.toString() method to convert rowNum into a String before assigning it to the String selection variable.

basically as the code is shown, you are sticking an int onto a string and assigning it to the String variable.  which is wrong.  that should be a class cast exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those things that is found within the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) - specifically, §15.18.1:

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

Ultimately, what's happening per [§5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) is a String conversion by converting either the primitive value to its Object counterpart (so `int` => `new Integer()`, `char` becomes `new Character()`, etc), and then `toString()` is called on that reference.

<sup>Long story short, yes; `Integer.toString()` is being called; but you are not obligated to call it - this is done as a requirement of string conversion.</sup>

Taken in bites:

- I don't know `_ID`'s type, but I'll presume that it's String.
- `" = '"` is a String literal. Combine this with the previous left-hand value and you have a new String.
- `rowNum` is an `int`.  Create a new `Integer` and call `toString()` on it, and concatenate the result.  You have a new String.
- `"';'"` is a String.  Combine this with the previously newed String and you have a new String.

Answer (score 1):

Its a kind of `Auto Boxing`, What happens here is

```
String.valueOf(rowNum)
```

You should have do this manually for `casting` an `int` to `String`. But java compiler will do this intellectually for the convenience of the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, `rowNumb` is an integer, but when you put it beside double quotation it will be treated a part of string literal.

for example:

```
int a = 3;
jtextField.setText(Integer.toString(a));
//or
jtextField.setText(""+a);
//are the not the same, but the second one is a tricky way to set
//an integer to the text field.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate a String with an int, Java tries to cast it to a String. Essentially, .toString is called on the Object, in this case an Integer.

You should work on your skills. This is something basic you should know...